# Azure pipeline generated NuGet packages will not install "seem empty"

Tags: c#, nuget, yaml, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

## NuGet Packages "seem Empty"

I have a solution that creates two `.dll` files.

- JReyLibrary - some common functions and controls.
- JRTestLib - Testing helps.

I was able to build NuGet Packages for both and install into an app, using the `classic pipeline`.
When I changed to the YAML pipeline I was able to build the packages but the will not install in the app.

The installation has no errors but do not show up in the references.

I am very confused some documentation says I do not need a `.nuspec` file if I have a `.csproj` file.

I do not have a `*[library]*.nuspec` file.

### Observations

Inspecting the .nuget\packages[library] I find that the directory structure is different.

#### Classic Pipeline

The following is an old Version that loads and is visible in the VS project References. This was created using the `classic pipeline`.

```
 Directory of C:\Users\james\.nuget\packages\jrtestlib\0.14.6535.24741

07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          .
07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/30/2020  07:39 AM               130 .nupkg.metadata
07/30/2020  07:39 AM             7,561 jrtestlib.0.14.6535.24741.nupkg
07/30/2020  07:39 AM                88 jrtestlib.0.14.6535.24741.nupkg.sha512
11/22/2017  01:45 PM               605 jrtestlib.nuspec
07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          lib
               4 File(s)          8,384 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\james\.nuget\packages\jrtestlib\0.14.6535.24741\lib

07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          .
07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          net40
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\james\.nuget\packages\jrtestlib\0.14.6535.24741\lib\net40

07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          .
07/30/2020  07:39 AM    <DIR>          ..
11/22/2017  01:45 PM            11,264 JRTestLib.dll
               1 File(s)         11,264 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               5 File(s)         19,648 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  389,112,635,392 bytes free
```

> Note: The `.dll` file is in contained in .\lib\net40 directory.

Am not able to show the `classic pipeline` steps because it says I cannot imbed an image.

There is one item that I was not able to translate to YAML. The `Output Variables` option contains `NuGetPackager_5` (JReyLibrary) and `NuGetPackager_11` (JRTestLib).

I also noticed that the Publisher Task is before the copy files task.

#### YAML Pipeline

This package was built using `YAML` to crate the packages.
These packages install without error but do not show up in the References of the project.

The following directory structure is found.

```
 Directory of C:\Users\james\.nuget\packages\jrtestlib\0.16.20201211.7

12/11/2020  03:09 PM    <DIR>          .
12/11/2020  03:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/11/2020  03:09 PM               130 .nupkg.metadata
12/11/2020  03:09 PM             6,708 jrtestlib.0.16.20201211.7.nupkg
12/11/2020  03:09 PM                88 jrtestlib.0.16.20201211.7.nupkg.sha512
12/11/2020  03:09 PM               586 jrtestlib.nuspec
12/11/2020  03:09 PM    <DIR>          tools
               4 File(s)          7,512 bytes

 Directory of C:\Users\james\.nuget\packages\jrtestlib\0.16.20201211.7\tools

12/11/2020  03:09 PM    <DIR>          .
12/11/2020  03:09 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/11/2020  03:09 PM            11,264 JRTestLib.dll
               1 File(s)         11,264 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               5 File(s)         18,776 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  388,888,588,288 bytes free
```

> Note: the `.dll` file is found in the ./Tools Directory.

Changing the app project References to this file directly compiles correctly.

The following shows the tasks to pack an publish the NuGet packages.

YAML pipeline snippit

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack JReyLibrary'
  env:
    packageversion: $(packageversion)
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: JLReyLibrary/JReyLibrary.csproj
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: packageversion
    includeSymbols: true
    toolPackage: true
  enabled: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet pack JRTestLib'
  env:
    packageversion: $(packageversion)
  inputs:
      command: pack
      packagesToPack: JLReyLibrary/JRTestLib/JRTestLib.csproj
      versioningScheme: byEnvVar
      versionEnvVar: packageversion
      includeSymbols: true
      toolPackage: true
  enabled: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: NuGet Push
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: 'jlr_feed'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
   SourceFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)'
   Contents: '**'
   TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

I do not see any documentation that will help this.

Comment: I have added a .nuspec file and run on the local computer on the local computer the .dll file is in the `lib` directory and when run in a pipeline the .dll is placed in the `tools` directory of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

The NuGetCommand contained the option `toolPackage: true` when this was removed it built a normal library.

This is solved

**Happy Boxing Day**

Comment: This may be closed